# Периодически пропадает интернет на персональном компьютере

Tags: wifi, железо, usb

Пропадает интернет, появляется только после перезагрузки компьютера, при этом если пропал интернет то компьютер невозможно выключить, все время крутиться заставка "Завершение работы". Windows 7. Интернет через usb wi-fi адаптер.

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать переставить винду. Но вообще-то usb wi-fi адаптеры разные бывают. Бывают ОЧЕНЬ кривые поделия с ОЧЕНЬ кривыми драйверами. Если такие вещи покупать, то только от ведущих производителей. Еще попробуйте перезагрузить wi-fi роутер. Может он глючит.

Comment: с роутером все ок, так как параллельно подключен ноут, работает без перебоев. Я думаю если бы была причина в адаптере, то достаточно было бы перезагрузить только его, а тут если пропал интернет, то сразу и комп не выключается...